# Do choices affect the story?

Tags: to-the-moon

There are several points where you have to make small choices in To The Moon, notably at the beginning when you have to chose between the two characters.

Does that choice affect the game a lot? I remember mostly controlling Dr. Watts after choosing him, but would choosing Dr. Rosalene mean that you see the story from her point of view? All in all, how linear is To The Moon?

Comment: I've finished the game using Dr. Rosalene, and the game was very linear. You can't even lose in the game. I haven't tried finishing the game again using Dr. Neils so I ain't sure if the story's point of view would change.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the choices make no difference to the overall story.  The choice of character in the beginning is only temporary, and doesn't change much - once you connect to the machine, everything else is the same.

*(source: played the game multiple times, because it's so great :D)*.